# What is the equation for this spiral related to sums of two squares?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, complex-numbers, polar-coordinates

In the Wikipedia page for the [sum of two squares theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_two_squares_theorem), there is the following image.

[image: Spiral]

The article calls attention to the Gaussian integers whose norms are integers, however I'm interested in the pink spiral underneath.

While I have considered formulations specifying what kind of spiral I would like, I have nothing precise and accurate. I would like to obtain an expression for a spiral that "grazes" key points such as those in the image -- that seem to correspond to numbers that are sums of two squares. I am mainly motivated by how natural the spiral in the image above looks.

A possible almost-formulation is that for every $a^2 + b^2, a, b \in\mathbb{N}$ there is a point on the spiral equal to $(A, B) + \epsilon$ for some $A = ±a, B = ±b$ and small $\epsilon$.

Comment: It does not seem this is an exact spiral.

Comment: @coffeemath Oh, my apologies. Should I edit the question to ask for some sort of smooth curve or something of the sort? Really not familiar with terminology here.

Comment: To me it would involve some kind of statistical regression to obtain a spiral which *approximates* the points in the plot. That would involve choosing an exact family for the spiral, having some parameters in it, and statistics to select one for best fit. However I think fitting a spiral would not be as simple as when fitting a line y=mx+b.

Comment: Thank you, I was indeed interested in the approximation. I have been trying to formalize what it is that I want but I am finding it quite difficult, so I will edit the question with the clarification.

Comment: You will note that if there is one Gaussian integer with norm $N>0$ then there are at least four, usually more. E.g., $\pm7\pm4i, \pm4\pm7i,\pm8\pm i,\pm1\pm8i$ all have norm $\sqrt{65}$. So it's not clear to me what "$|f(p)-(a+bi)|$ is minimal for all $f(\theta)$" means, when there are many numbers $a+bi$ giving the same norm. It is not clear how the particular $a+bi$ in the diagram is chosen, or whether a different choice would also give such a spiral.

Comment: Thank you for that, I will have to amend the formulation.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Upon revision I believe I have misunderstood and should ask for clarification. Minimal $|f(p) - (a+bi)|$ over all $f(\theta)$ refers to the closest $f(\theta)$ to the given $(a+bi)$, so the ambiguity in the norms for, for instance $(7,4)$ and $(1,8)$ does not contradict the existence of distinct $f(p)$ for both. Though these wouldn't count as $\sqrt{65}$ is not integral. To me it seems clear that such a unique closest point exists in the spiral, but is this incorrect? In addition, I suspect my wording was imprecise -- how should I rewrite that clause to match what I've said here?

Comment: I have understood the diagram's mismatch with my formulation, and edited the question to reduce the space to the Gaussian integers unique up to x or y reflections.

Comment: I think the spiral is going through points where $a^2+b^2$ is integral, not where $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ is integral. E.g., look at the point with the big $26$ on it – that's at $1+ 5i$, and $1^2+5^2=26$. The modulus of $a+bi$ as a complex number, or the norm of $(a,b)$ as a point in ${\bf R}^2$, is $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$, but the norm of $a+bi$ as a Gaussian integer is $a^2+b^2$. Confusing, aye, but those are the conventions.

Comment: You're right, it seems I had a fundamental misunderstanding about what points they chose to depict on the spiral. It almost seems like it's the other way around - the spiral goes through norms of $(a, b)$ in order, but it's unclear to me how they can obtain such a natural shape for the spiral with such a bizarre condition.